# Twitter bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use https://github.com/mgussekloo/my-bootstrap-datetimepicker with twitter bootstrap but it doesn't work. I don't know how it could not be working because I just followed the example, no customization.

P.S.
There is the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'.

I'm not sure if I do it right, so here's the code for the input:

```
<input type="text" class="data-datepicker-format" data-datepicker-format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [this date/time picker](http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). It is really simple to use and also implements fast keyboard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments to another answer, the issue seems to be that you're loading both Bootstrap DatePicker and jqueryUI DatePicker libraries.

If you really do need to use jqueryUI, you'll need to build a jqueryUI package without the DatePicker. You can do that on the [jqueryUI download site](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

***EDIT***: To be clear, you can leave jquery in place. Only jquery-**UI** needs to be either removed, or you need a custom jqueryUI package that excludes the DatePicker.

Comment: I've looked at the link above and found out that I don't have such a calendar (as datepicker demo). And both files I've mentioned above do not have function 'datepicker'. And I've tried to use it on a clean project whithout jquery.js, fail again. Is there a demo or any analog of datetime pickers for RoR projects that look like twitter bootstrap? Thanks.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line where you call .datepicker(). Fire up your app and wait for the breakpoint to be hit, then inspect the state of things: Is bootstrap.js loaded? Is datepicker.js loaded?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I was able to fix the error, but it is fixed by now. I just began from the beginning (again) and it worked. The next step is to grab the value from the text input and pass it to the datetime field in the database. Anyway thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to include datepicker.js in your scripts section?

```
<script src="/path/to/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure that datepicker.js is loaded **after** the bootstrap main library is loaded, and **before** your script where you call .datepicker() is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is loaded properly. Though it is not working. And yes, I've enabled JS in my browsers (tested in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Are you by chance loading jqueryUI? It has its own .datepicker method that may be interfering.

Comment: I'd also do some sanity checks: load up your site, put a breakpoint on your foo.datepicker() call. When that fires, verify that foo is a jquery object, verify that you see bootstrap.js and datepicker.js in the loaded JS files. Chrome or Firebug will work for this.

Comment: Yes, I'm loading the following files:

    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: What exactly should I change to make both .js files work together? I cannot turn off jquery because some of its functions are used by my webapp.

Comment: To fix this, you need to either exclude jqueryUI (if you're not using it), or build a custom jqueryUI package that excludes the jqueryUI DatePicker.